# How to prevent parent component from reloading when changing a parameterised child component in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a page where a ClientPortfolio (parent component) containing a list of Securities (child component) are loaded in a v-data-table list.

[image]

The issue I have is that ClientPortfolio is fully reloaded every time I click on a security in the list causing the entire list to be refreshed causing scroll and selected class to reset, as well as unncessary performance overhead.
I have looked at the documentation of Vue and nothing seems to point out how to only refresh a child component when it has parameters, it looks like the parent component is being refreshed as the route is changing every time a security is selected, despite expecting that Vue would *know* that only sub (nested route) is changing hence need to only reload the child component

[image]

The closest answer I got was explained on https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/230 which does not explain in the code how to achieve this.

> routes.js:

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/client/:clientno/portfolios/:portfolioNo',
      component: ClientPortfolios,
      children: [
        { path: 'security/:securityNo', component: Security }
      ]     
    }, 
  ]
```

> Router link in ClientPortfolios.vue:

```
 <router-link tag="tr" style="cursor:pointer"
              :to="`/client/${$route.params.clientno}/portfolios/${selectedPortfolioSequenceNo}/security/${props.item.SecurityNo}-${props.item.SequenceNo}`"
              :key="props.item.SecurityNo+props.item.SequenceNo">

            </router-link>
```

> Router view (for Security component) in ClientPortfolios.vue:

```
<v-flex xs10 ml-2>
      <v-layout>
          <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
```

Any hint on how to prevent parent from getting reloaded is appreciated.

EDIT: Trying to get closer to the issue, I notice that the "Key" attr in ClientPortfolios changes (as shown in the Vue debug window above) whenever I change the Security, could that be the reason? Is there a way to assign a key to ClientPortfolios component although its not a child one? Or a way to not update its key when navigating to different securities?

UPDATE: Full code

> ClientPortfolios.vue

```
<template>
  <v-layout row fill-height>
    <v-flex xs2>
      <v-layout column class="ma-0 pa-0 elevation-1">
        <v-flex>
          <v-select v-model="selectedPortfolioSequenceNo" :items="clientPortfolios" box label="Portfolio"
            item-text="SequenceNo" item-value="SequenceNo" v-on:change="changePortfolio">
          </v-select>
        </v-flex>
        <v-data-table disable-initial-sort :items="securities" item-key="Id" hide-headers hide-actions
          style="overflow-y: auto;display:block;height: calc(100vh - 135px);">
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <router-link tag="tr" style="cursor:pointer"
              :to="{ name: 'Security', params: { securityNo: props.item.SecurityNo+'-'+props.item.SequenceNo } }"
              >
            </router-link>

          </template>
          <template v-slot:no-data>
            <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
              No securities found
            </v-flex>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs10 ml-2>
      <v-layout>
        <keep-alive>
          <router-view></router-view>
        </keep-alive>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>

</template>
<script>
  import Security from '@/components/Security'

  export default {
    components: {

      security: Security
    },
    data () {
      return {
        portfoliosLoading: false,
        selectedPortfolioSequenceNo: this.$route.params.portfolioNo,
        selectedPortfolio: null,
        securityNo: this.$route.params.securityNo
      }
    },
    computed: {
      clientPortfolios () {
        return this.$store.state.ClientPortfolios
      },
      securities () {
        if (this.clientPortfolios == null || this.clientPortfolios.length < 1) {
          return []
        }
        let self = this
        this.selectedPortfolio = global.jQuery.grep(this.clientPortfolios, function (portfolio, i) {
          return portfolio.SequenceNo === self.selectedPortfolioSequenceNo
        })[0]

        return this.selectedPortfolio.Securities
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getClientPortfolios()
    },
    activated () {
    },
    methods: {
      changePortfolio () {
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/client/' + this.$route.params.clientno + '/portfolios/' + this.selectedPortfolioSequenceNo
        })
      },
      getClientPortfolios: function () {
        this.portfoliosLoading = true
        let self = this
        this.$store.dispatch('getClientPortfolios', {
          clientNo: this.$route.params.clientno
        }).then(function (serverResponse) {
          self.portfoliosLoading = false
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> Security.vue

```
<template>
  <v-flex>
    <v-layout class="screen-header">
      <v-flex class="screen-title">Security Details </v-flex>

    </v-layout>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-layout align-center justify-space-between row class="contents-placeholder" mb-3 pa-2>
      <v-layout column>
        <v-flex class="form-group" id="security-portfolio-selector">
          <label class="screen-label">Sequence</label>
          <span class="screen-value">{{security.SequenceNo}}</span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex class="form-group">
          <label class="screen-label">Security</label>
          <span class="screen-value">{{security.SecurityNo}}-{{security.SequenceNo}}</span>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex class="form-group">
          <label class="screen-label">Status</label>
          <span class="screen-value-code" v-if="security.Status !== ''">{{security.Status}}</span>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>

    </v-layout>

  </v-flex>

</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['securityNo'],
    data () {
      return {
        clientNo: this.$route.params.clientno,
        securityDetailsLoading: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
      security () {
        return this.$store.state.SecurityDetails
      }
    },

    created () {
      if (this.securityNo.length > 1) {
        this.getSecurityDetails()
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getSecurityDetails: function () {
        let self = this
        this.securityDetailsLoading = true

        this.$store.dispatch('getSecurityDetails', {
          securityNo: this.securityNo,
          clientNo: this.clientNo

        }).then(function (serverResponse) {
          self.securityDetailsLoading = false
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

> router.js

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/client/:clientno/details',
      component: Client,
      props: true
    },

    {
      path: '/client/:clientno/portfolios/:portfolioNo',
      component: ClientPortfolios,
      name: 'ClientPortfolios',
      children: [
        { path: 'security/:securityNo',
          component: Security,
          name: 'Security'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

**UPDATE**:

Just to update this as it’s been a while, I finally got to find out what the problem is, which is what @matpie indicated elsewhere, I have found out that my App.vue is the culprit where there is a :key add to the very root of the application: `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />` this was a template I used from somewhere but never had to look at as it was "working", after removing the key, all is working as it should, marking matpie answer accepted.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle or equivalent?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use vuex to store the current selected security rather than using a router to load child components? Then you can just grab the child data whenever the vuex store property changes.

Comment: How is this going to solve reloading the ClientPortfolio when the security is changed? I could vuex to store securities etc. but parent component still needs to be reloaded once. Also, I have many thousands of securities in each portfolio, I dont think vuex is designed to store such amount od data.

Comment: it would be good if you can share more code. Have you tried to wrap your component with <keep-alive> <component></component></keep-alive>

Comment: The above is literally all code I have for the 3 parts where the navigation, I cant imagine I could add anything relevant to the issue

Comment: What is it that indicates your parent component is reloading? What does _"reloading"_ actually mean in this context?

Comment: Since the path of parent '/client/:clientno/portfolios/:portfolioNo' is a subset of the child's path '/client/:clientno/portfolios/:portfolioNo/security/:securityNo' (as you can see in routes.js above) the parent route gets triggered and the list of securities gets refreshed (reloading mean full life cycle of the parent activates like, created, mounted.. and the rest)

Comment: You don't happen to have a :key defined on your top-level <router-view> by any chance? If so, that's probably the issue

Comment: I actually had one there ( <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>) but didnt work either and I removed it, I updated the question though.

Comment: May be you can use the beforeRouteEnter hook to prevent the reload

Comment: Are you using `watch` in any of your parent component ?

Comment: No watch anywhere

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Preventing component reload is the default behavior in Vue.js. Vue's reactivity system automatically maps property dependencies and only performs the minimal amount of work to ensure the DOM is current.

By using a `:key` attribute anywhere, you are telling Vue.js that this element or component should *only* match when the keys match. If the keys don't match, the old one will be destroyed and a new one created.

It looks like you're also pulling in route parameters on the data object (`Security.vue`). Those will not update when the route parameters change, you should pull them in to a computed property so that they will always stay up-to-date.

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    clientNo: (vm) => vm.$route.params.clientno,
  }
}
```

That will ensure that `clientNo` always matches what is found in the router, regardless of whether Vue decides to re-use this component instance. If you need to perform other side-effects when `clientNo` changes, you can add a watcher:

```js
vm.$watch("clientNo", (clientNo) => { /* ... */ })
```

Comment: I appreciate the info here about data vs watch, but how is this meant to resolve the issue of no triggering the ClientPortfolios component when the security changes? Unless I did not understand your answer clearly? At the moment I have a portfolioNo (param for ClientPortfolio) and securitNo (param for Security) in the route, when securityNo changes both ClientPortfolio and Security reload, where I want only Security to acticate, not ClientPortfolio.

Comment: @Maya, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "reload". Are the lifecycle hooks executing again? Vue only re-evaluates portions which are out-of-date. That's the nature of Vue's data-driven design. If you're seeing something reload entirely, it's likely elsewhere in your codebase and not what you've shared here so far.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean, the lifecycle hooks, (created, mounted, and the rest) are triggered in ClientPortfolio when I change the security, and thats exactly what I'm trying to fix, stopping lifecycle hooks from executing on ClientPortfolio, what do suggest to do? share App.vue and main.js and the ret of it? (although as far as I know nothing seems done wrong or unusual there)

Comment: So if `ClientPortfolio` is reloading, my best guess is that you have a `:key` on it as well, make sure to remove all `:key` attributes from `<router-view>`s.

Comment: I have no keys any where there, I have removed the key from router-view, still no difference in the behaviour, I really cant thinl of anything that causes this issue to happen

Comment: Just to update this as it’s been a while, I finally got to find out what the problem is, which is what @matpie indicated elsewhere, I have found out that my App.vue is the culprit where there is a :key add to the very root of the application: <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" /> this was a template I used from somewhere but never had to look at as it was "working", after removing the key, all is working as it should, marking matpie answer accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad you got it all sorted, @Maya!

Comment: Oh God thank you very much for this answer. I've been struggling for like 2 weeks now with a very similar problem, and with your answer I finally managed to make it work just as I wanted! If I could I would give you all my reputation!

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check again after removing the local registration of the security component? As it's not needed because this is being handled by the vue router itself.

```
components: { // delete this code

      security: Security
    },
```

Comment: Done, No difference

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using router here. Declare two variable at root level for selected security and portfolio,

list the securities based on the selected portfolio.

on selecting a security from displayed securities, update the root variable using,

```
this.$root.selectedSecurityId = id;
```

you can have `watch` at security component level.

In root,

```
<security selectedid="selectedSecurityId" />
```

In component `security`,

```
....
watch:{
   selectedid:function(){
   //fetch info and show
   }
}
...
```

the components will be look like following,

```
<portfolio>
  //active. list goes here
</portfolio>
........
<security selectedid="selectedSecurityId">
//info goes here
</security>
```

Above approach will help to avoid routers. hope this will help.

Comment: But without routers, can users have the final url of specific securities without the need to navigate through clients and portfolios? Copying and pasting a url for security is important for users to exchange through emails/chat etc.

Comment: That is a very good approach. For that, we can load a single page in router and read the passed security and portfolio from the url and load accordingly. If no security id or portfolio passed show the default page. Set the top level variables on passing the info as part of the URL.

Comment: use URl like `<context>/<portfolio>/<securityId>`. So that you can avoid using static keyords.

Comment: But how updating security using this.$root.selectedSecurityId = id will update the route? I dont get it

Comment: @Kajal... you can use gists

Comment: @sureshvv Thank you so much. gitst url is : https://gist.github.com/pradeeppanayal/0703f37b4b18edead3a71f7ad0160fd4

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue once. IMO it was caused by path string parsing.
Try to set a name for your route. And replace your router-link `to` param with an object.
And remove router-view `:key` prop. It doesn't need to be there. It is used to force component update when a route changes. It is usually a sign of bad code. Your component (`Security`) should react to route params update. Not the parent component force it to.

So, try to change your code to:

```js
routes: [
    {
      path: '/client/:clientno/portfolios/:portfolioNo',
      component: ClientPortfolios,
      name: "ClientPortfoliosName", // it can be anything you want. It`s just an alias for internal use.
      children: [
        { 
           path: 'security/:securityNo', 
           name: "PortfolioSecurities", // anyway, consider setting route names as good practice
           component: Security 
        }
      ]     
    }, 
  ]
```

```html
 <router-link tag="tr" style="cursor:pointer"
              :to="{ name: 'PortfolioSecurities', params: { clientno: $route.params.clientno, portfolioNo: selectedPortfolioSequenceNo, securityNo: props.item.SecurityNo+'-'+props.item.SequenceNo } }"
              :key="props.item.SecurityNo+props.item.SequenceNo">

            </router-link>
```

And it should work.

P.S. In your `router-link` you shall point to the route you want to navigate to. In this case `PortfolioSecurities`

Comment: Just did everthing as you instructed, still it does not work, same issue, once clicked on a different security both ClientPortfolios and Security components get activated.

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange. Have you removed all ``:key`` bindings from router-views? As your screenshot shows you also have binding to your router-view placed inside ``v-content``.

Comment: I did, removed the key from <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>, and there is no v-content keys or bindings what you see in the screenshot is automatically displayed, I dont know how, but looks like the only place is coming from is the route definition itself

Comment: At the screenshot you provided there is a ``key`` prop binding. And it is bound to route. IMO, this causes an issue. Can you post code from your App.vue or something? The part with router-view?

Comment: Added full code, I dont see anything that might influence the ClientPortfolios to have a key.

Comment: I don't see where you use ``ClientPortfolios``. Can you post it from App.vue or where you use it?

Comment: Adding a `:key` to the `<router-link>` will do nothing useful here.

Comment: In this specific case, I suppose that ``<router-link>`` is placed inside ``v-for`` block. And it makes sense.

Comment: @IvanKlochkov ClientPortfolios component is activated throught routes.js entry, when the url matches the route

Comment: Nope, it gets mounted in place of your top-level hierarchy <router-view>. And I'm sure that router-view has ``:key`` binding. Which causes reload.

Comment: <router-view> has no keys, i checked, I double check, still same problem